# Storing user selection and data

Tags: javascript

Is there a way to store user selection into a variable?

For example, a=1, b=2, c=3. I have options that increments these values by 2. Option 1 is default value. Option 2 is a=3, b=4, c=5. Option 3 is a=5, b=6, c=7. And so on.

I need to store these values each time the user changes option. I don't want hard coded value that each option represents. I want to use calculation based on current value. For example, going from options 2 to options 6, I need to calculate based on the 4 options apart, not just options 6 will equal a=11, b=12, c=13.

Most importantly, I need to store the current selected option in a variable, so that I know that if the next option a user select is either greater or lesser than current selected option.

For example, i = 0, if user selects options 3, i = selectedIndex (which is 2). By knowing this, I need to have a code that does "if nextSelection is less than i, a, b, and c, will equal to it's respective value." So if user selects option 4 and than option 2, a, b, and c will be reduced by 4. If user selects option 4 and than option 6, a, b, and c will increment by 4.

I've tried something like

```
var i = 0

if(test.selectedIndex >= i){
    a = a + (selectedIndex + 1) * 2
    *same with b and c and so on*

    i = selectedIndex
}
```

Problem is, "i" remains 0 on change of options. This would also be a problem if I go from options 2 to 4, because options 2 to 4 would only increment the current value by 4, and (selectedIndex + 1 ) * 2 causes option 4 to increment by 8.

Comment: please add some examples of input and output.

Comment: btw, it looks like you need a better data structure, like an array or an object.

Comment: I don't know what other examples I can give for knowing if user selects a n option that is greater or lesser than current selection, like selecting option 1, than selecting option 3, than selecting option 2.

Comment: Can you create a working [snippet](https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/) it will save a lot of time of trying understand your meaning.

Comment: like others noted. how are you getting your input? Through an input, select, textarea, div?

Comment: Through select input.

Answer (score 0):

for example if you have dropdown, you can use:

```
var _Selected = document.getElementById("yourdropdownID");
var _SelectedIndex = _Selected.options[_Selected.selectedIndex].value;
```

and the _SelectedIndex will be the Index of selected Item.
You can store Previous selected Index in a temporary variable or use cookies.

Comment: How do I check if the next selection is greater than or lesser than current selection? Given that option 1 is less than option 2 and option 3 is greater than option 2. Coming from python, I know I can use a loop to accomplish this.

Comment: as you can NOT select 2 Index at a time, You can store Previous selected Index in a local memory and Update it in every selection:

Comment: That is exactly what my original question was. How to store user selection. Like using the "i" variable to store selectedIndex, and then do something based off of the next selectedIndex being greater than or lesser than "i". Would I need a loop to accomplish this?

Comment: yes.something like switch-case loop, you will compare "i" with temporary variable, and in each case, you will update the temp variable.